# Write data into read-end of a pipe or vice versa

Tags: pipe, file-descriptors

From [pipe manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)

> A pipe has a read end and a write end.  Data written to the write end of a pipe can be read from the read end of the pipe.

My understanding is that pipe is **a buffer** (in memory) created by kernel. I assume that the read-end and write-end is just 2 file descriptors referring to the **same underlying buffer**. Am I right about this?

What will happen if I try to write into the read-end of the pipe, or try to read from the write-end of the pipe? Will it fail? And if it does, is it because of intentional restriction put on it (read-end is RDONLY and write-end is WRONLY - I assume)?

Comment: yes, yes, and yes. Do not remember the exact errno you will get, but read/write will fail. And yes, it is intentional design decision. If you want a two-way communication, use a normal temp file. Or shared memory segment controlled by you.

Comment: You can of course create two pipes, and launch a child process such that the child gets a read end and a write end, and the parent keeps the corresponding write end and read end. It is necessary to impose a protocol to avoid a circular deadlock, where each process is waiting for the other to read something to unclag the buffering.

Comment: thanks! @WhiteOwl do you happen to know why its designed this way?